# Where does the JSON exist? Where can I put it

Tags: jquery, json, filemaker

I thought I found exactly what I was looking for. There is an amazing jsfiddle page that has a webform where, when submitted, displays the JSON string of that forms data.

http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/ 
load (to pick one) FireFox->lower right frame->right-click->this frame->view framesource->save as and it works as opened [unserved] file in browser -- very self contained. Amazing!

However, and be gentle 'cause JS jQuery are not my things, I don't know how to access the JSON string that results.

I *can* select the result and copy it (or select it an right-click->view selection source), here is an example:

```
{
    "Fname":"Le Bron",
    "Lname":"James",
    "gender":"Male",
    "food[]":["Steak","Pizza","Chicken"],
    "quote":"If you meet the Buddha in the lane, feed him the ball.\r\nPhil Jackson\r\n",
    "education":"HighSchool",
    "TofD":"Night"
}
```

Also, when I inspect the element it's there.

However, I was hoping that the results would *exist* in the "View Source" (Content) value, since I can programmatically gather either the URL or the Content within a FileMaker WebViewer object.

I really like to use 'data:text/html,' prefix and compose web content within FM. I was hoping that I could compose a web from and capture the result via JSON object as returned above, but "where does it go?" and/or "how can I put it in the content?" (or URL, but...)

Comment: A couple of thoughts: as a work-around to not being able to get the modified page source, you could write a JavaScript that re-loads the page, but this time includes the data you want in the HTML, which you will now be able to grab because it was there at the time the page loaded. Much easier, you could use an fmurl and call a script with a parameter: https://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/sharing_data.16.7.html

Answer (score 0):

Filemaker gives you access to the web viewer's content - which is the same thing you get when you do 'view page source' in any browser. However, this only reveals the source code of the HTML page. Any content that is generated by a script when (or after) the page loads, is not accessible from within Filemaker.